# Programming dplyr operations

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Any idea how I can manipulate dplyr variables programatically?

This works:

```
out = "new_var"
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(!!out := mpg/carb)
```

But I really need to be able to adjust the variables in the division. Thought I could do it like this:

```
out = "new_var"
numer = "mpg"
denom = "carb"
mtcars %>%
  mutate(!!out := !! quo(numer/denom))
```

but no dice:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

result should look like:

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   new_var
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  5.250000
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  5.250000
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 22.800000
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 21.400000
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  9.350000
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 18.100000
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4  3.575000
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 12.200000
...
```

Any idea how this works?

SOLVED -------------------------------------------------

```
myFunction = function(df, col, col2, new_col) {
    col <- enquo(col)
    col2 <- enquo(col2)
    new_col <- quo_name(enquo(new_col))

    df %>% 
        mutate(!!new_col := (!!col)/(!!col2))
}

myFunction(mtcars, mpg, wt, mpg_based_new_col)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a quosure from a character value, you can use the `rlang::sym()` function (or just the base `as.name()` function). For example

```
out = "new_var"
numer = rlang::sym("mpg")
denom = rlang::sym("carb")
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(!!out := (!!numer)/(!!denom))
```

Note how we escape each variable separately rather than the entire expression.

Comment: Nice...yeah i didn't want it to be a character value ultimately...probably should have thought of that before posting

Comment: @Dan You can also create quosures with  `numer = quo(mpg)` -- the importanr part is to just treat each variable separately if you want to pop in different things rather than doing the entire expression.